# Setting a standard Date/Time format in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

What is the best practice for creating a standard date/time format in Rails? We have  statements similar to this:

```
def get_formatted_due_date
    self.DueDate.try { |d| d.strftime("%m/%d/%y %l:%M%P")}
end
```

or

```
ScheduledSendDate.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%y %l:%M%P")
```

However, this solution does not seem very dry or elegant. Is there a way to set a default format and use this over and over?

Update:
I've added a config/initializers/date_and_time_format.rb file with:

`Time::DATE_FORMATS[:my_format] = '%m/%d/%y %l:%M%P' # 02/22/13 12:30pm`

In the code I've switched to using:

```
def get_formatted_due_date
    self.DueDate.try { |d| d.strftime(:my_format)}
end
```

and

```
ScheduledSendDate.try(:to_s, :my_format)
```

This seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: Use I18n.localize - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

Comment: Yep. You answered your own question. That's the way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
DateTime.new(params[:year],params[:month],params[:day])
```

or

```
require 'date'
date = DateTime.civil( *params.values_at( :year, :month, :day ) )
```

or a time zone one...

```
Set the time zone of the TimeWithZone instance
Time.zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

Get current time using the time zone you set
Time.zone.now

Convert from unix timestamp back to time format using the time zone you set
Time.zone.at(1364046539)

Convert from unix timestamp back to time format using the time zone you set,
and the required string format => "03/23/13 09:48 AM"
Time.at(1364046539).in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p")
```

Anyways i havent touched on rails for ages aha tell me if it doesnt work or if it wasnt want you meant